# Problem generating PDF using Laravel Spatie/Browsershot

Tags: laravel, pdf, puppeteer, browsershot

I 'm trying to generate a PDF using the below code:

`$content = view('bills.show', ['bill' => $bill])->render(); return Browsershot::html($content)->setNodeBinary('C:/PROGRA~1/nodejs/node.exe')->pdf();`

however i am getting this error (attaching full stack trace as well):

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException The command
> "C:/PROGRA^~1/nodejs/node.exe
> ^"C:^\Codex^\hidma-backend^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^"
> ^"^{^^"url^^":^^"file:^/^/C:^^\Users^^\alex.DFK^^\AppData^^\Local^^\Temp^^\873677827-0646160001622728448^^\index.html^^",^^"action^^":^^"pdf^^",^^"options^^":^{^^"args^^":^[^],^^"viewport^^":^{^^"width^^":800,^^"height^^":600^},^^"displayHeaderFooter^^":false^}^}^""
> failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory:
> C:\Codex\hidma-backend\public Output: ================ Error Output:
> ================ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path:
> 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }

[image: stack trace]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar error by creating a "temp" drive (on my Windows system: C:\temp)

Comment: this doesn't works